# How to call a function within a python file that is a part of some other python file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-importlib

the title might not be correct but this the closest i could think of.

I'm having a file **sample.py** which is like a command line parser made using **argparse**.
Based on the arguments it is invoking other python files.
E.g. - to compile a module option in -C.

```
cmd>python sample.py -M module -C
```

Based on module name, the configuration file is under module/configuration.py

I have to call few functions from configuration.py file. What is the best way to do.
I can't import the python files since the path will always vary and file needs to be imported at runtime.

Is there some way to solve this issue?

I have read about  importlib package but couldn't get it to work for my use.

***Structure of my framework:***

```
sample.py
|
APIs
   |
    compile.py

/module/configuration.py
```

compile.py file sample

```
 #compile.py
import <packages>

def compile(module_name):
    # call some function in /module/configuration.py file.
```

The issue is that module_name is passed in compile function hence i can't use in importing.

My question may be too long or too obvious but i have been struggling a lot. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
# Equivalent to dynamically `import`ing `module`
moduleName = 'module.configuration'
module = __import__(moduleName)
```

**BTW**, `__import__()` is a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html), so you may access it from anywhere. Although it's a little more complex/sofisticated than `importlib.import_module()`, it's pretty much more flexible, and, contrary to what the documentation says, it can be very useful in everyday code.

Comment: `run_py_file_path = "../../module/setup/configuration.py"
run_py_file_module = __import__(str(run_py_file_path))
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.` Not sure what is the issue here.

Comment: @AmitGoel: You can't `import`/`__import__()` by *filesystem path*, but by *module path*. That's a basic rule. You should do something like: `import sys; sys.path.append('../..'); run_py_module_path = "module.setup.configuration"; run_py_module = __import__(run_py_module_path);` and you'll be okay :).

Comment: @AmitGoel: If you're going to use `__import__()`, you need to add the parent directory of `module` (it doesn't matter if the actual stuff is inside `module`) to `sys.path`. It doesn't matter if such a path is relative or absolute.

Comment: the issue is that ../../<module>/setup/*.py in this path the module is variable and will be provided by user. That is why i have saved it in a variable run_py_file_path. Now i'm doing `sys.path.append(run_py_file_path); run_py_file_module = __import__(run_py_file_path)` but still getting same error. I know im doing something stupid. please can you correct me.

Comment: @AmitGoel: If `<module>` is variable, and is always located in `../..`, and there's no more clutter involved, this should solve it once and for all: `import sys; import os.path; sys.path.append('../..'); module_name = 'foo'; script_name = 'configuration.py'; __import__(os.path.join(module_name, 'setup', script_name))`. Tell me/us if you have any other doubts :).

Comment: @AmitGoel: **BTW**: Your last example didn't worked because you were `append()`ing something that's *not* a directory (`run_py_file_path`) to `sys.path`, the place where you put the *directories* that `import` and `__import__()` use to map module names (such as `module.setup.configuration`) to actual filenames (such as `../../module/setup/configuration.py`).

Comment: `module_name_vista = module_1
run_py_file = configuration.py
sys.path.append('../../../../validation')
run_py_file_module = __import__(os.path.join(module_name_vista, 'setup', run_py_file))`
@KemyLand : Thanks for helping me out. I'm still getting same error. Dont know what is going wrong. Im using the way you suggested.

Comment: @AmitGoel: Oh! Sorry, it was my fault, replace `os.path.join(module_name_vista, 'setup', run_py_file)` with `'.'.join([module_name_vista, 'setup', run_py_file])` and remove the `.py` from `run_py_file`.

Comment: thanks. Just to add <module> and <setup> are directories. getting error: `ImportError: No module named nexus.setup.nexus_run`

Comment: @AmitGoel: Did you put the (empty) `__init__.py` files in `nexus` and `setup`? You should, otherwise Python won't recognize the directories as modules.

Comment: it worked now just last thing left. How to call a function in configuration.py. Simply by run_py_file_module.function() or i'll to do something more. This is last thing then my query is solved. Thanks for you quick repsonse.

Comment: @AmitGoel: Yes, that's everything you need to do :).

Comment: `    run_py_file_module.my_function()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'my_function'` I'm getting error by doing so. configuration.py file has only `def my_function():
    print "Im in run py"`.

Comment: @AmitGoel: Then you have just done something wrong in the previous steps. Please post the *whole* fragment of code that you made up from my comments.

Comment: my code is: `run_py_file = config.py
module_name_vista = m1
sys.path.append('../../../../validation')
# last parameter: only taking file name without extension
run_py_file_module = __import__('.'.join([module_name_vista, 'setup', run_py_file.split(".py")[0]]))
run_py_file_module.my_function()`
config.py file is as follows:
`def my_function():
    print "Im in run py"`

Comment: @AmitGoel: It happens that you're importing a submodule (`m1.setup.config`), and thus you should do something like `run_py_file_module.setup.config.my_function()`. To overcome this, you may do something like: `
def dynamic_import():
  `

Comment: @AmitGoel: Sorry, I missed the 5-minutes comment edit limit. Please ignore the previous comment. The code for is: `def dynamic_import(base_module, *submodules): return eval('__import__(\'' + '.'.join((base_module,) + submodules) + '\')' + ('.' + '.'.join(submodules)) if len(submodules) > 0 else '')`. Then, you can `sys.path.append('../../../../validation'); run_py_file_module = dynamic_import(module_name_vista, 'setup', run_py_file.split('.py')[0]); run_py_file_module.my_function();` and be happy :).